# Modals and laravel

Tags: php, wamp, microsoft-edge, laravel-livewire, sweetalert2

MyApp is a laravel application that has features that only run using listeners that display modals that no longer work

I uninstalled and reinstalled SweetAlert because that's where thé modals were pulled from. I alors proofread the code but no error is there

Comment: Without any code it's hard to provide any useful answer